# VBA code change to 64 bit. Macro to factor sales not working

Tags: excel, vba

I inherited a very useful macro that now doesn't work on our new 64bit machines - I have amended the front to have the PtrSafe code which seems to work but am now getting a fault on the below macro that I use all the time. The macro works by amending the highlighted cells value to that of the new inputted number: The error seems to highlight the first = Mid code, but it also highlights in yellow the first line.

> (Public Function ConcatAll(rngCells As Range, Optional pstrSep$ = "") As String)

Any help would be awesome.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function ConcatAll(rngCells As Range, Optional pstrSep$ = "") As String
  'Concatenates the text values in the specified range
  'Useful when coverting weeks to months

  Dim c As Range
  ConcatAll = ""

  For Each c In rngCells
    If c.Value <> "" Then
      ConcatAll = ConcatAll & pstrSep & c.Value
    End If

  Next

  ConcatAll = Mid(ConcatAll, Len(pstrSep) + 1)

End Function

Public Function ConcatUnique(rngCells As Range, Optional pstrSep$ = "") As String
  'Concatenates the text values in the specified range, only if the value has not been concatenated already
  'Useful when coverting weeks to months

  Dim c As Range, strConcat$
  strConcat = ""

  For Each c In rngCells

    If c.Value <> "" Then
      If InStr(1, strConcat, c.Value) = 0 Then
        strConcat = strConcat & pstrSep & c.Value
      End If

    End If

  Next

  ConcatUnique = Mid(strConcat, Len(pstrSep) + 1)

End Function


Public Function RPad(pstrSubj$, pintLen%, Optional pstrPad$ = " ") As String
'Pads out the right hand end of a given string with another character

  If Len(pstrSubj) >= pintLen Then
    RPad = pstrSubj

  Else
    Dim irpt%, strRes$
    strRes = pstrSubj
    Do Until Len(strRes & pstrPad) > pintLen
      strRes = strRes & pstrPad
    Loop

    If Len(strRes) < pintLen Then
      strRes = strRes & Left(pstrPad, pintLen - Len(strRes))
    End If

    RPad = strRes

  End If

End Function

Public Function LPad(pstrSubj$, pintLen%, Optional pstrLPad$ = " ") As String
'Pads out the left hand end of a given string with another character

  If Len(pstrSubj) >= pintLen Then
    LPad = pstrSubj

  Else
    Dim irpt%, strRes$
    strRes = pstrSubj
    Do Until Len(strRes & pstrLPad) > pintLen
      strRes = pstrLPad & strRes
    Loop

    If Len(strRes) < pintLen Then
      strRes = Left(pstrLPad, pintLen - Len(strRes)) & strRes
    End If

    LPad = strRes

  End If

End Function

Public Function ConcatIf(rngCells As Range, psCond$, Optional pstrSep$ = "", Optional prngVals As Range) As String
  'Concatenates the text values in the specified range if the condition is satisfied
  'Useful when coverting weeks to months

  ConcatIf = ""

  Dim rngVals As Range

  If Not (prngVals Is Nothing) Then
    If RngShapeEq(rngCells, prngVals) = True Then
      Set rngVals = prngVals

    Else
      'Ranges do not equal - return blank
      ConcatIf = "#Error"
      Exit Function

    End If

  Else
    Set rngVals = rngCells

  End If

  Dim iCell%, c As Range
  iCell = 1

  For Each c In rngCells

    If IsError(c) Then
      ConcatIf = "Error in cell " & c.Address
      Exit Function
    ElseIf IsError(rngVals.Cells(iCell)) Then
      ConcatIf = "Error in cell " & rngVals.Cells(iCell).Address
      Exit Function
    Else

      If Application.CountIf(c, psCond) > 0 Then

        ConcatIf = ConcatIf & pstrSep & rngVals.Cells(iCell).Value

      End If
    End If

    iCell = iCell + 1

  Next

  ConcatIf = Mid(ConcatIf, Len(pstrSep) + 1)

End Function

Private Function RngShapeEq(prng1 As Range, prng2 As Range) As Boolean
'Determines if the range shapes are equal

  RngShapeEq = False

  If prng1.Rows.Count = prng2.Rows.Count Then
    If prng1.Columns.Count = prng2.Columns.Count Then

      RngShapeEq = True

    End If
  End If


End Function


Public Function LTrim(pText$, Optional pTrimCh$ = " ") As String
'Trims the left end of the string with pTrimCh

  Dim intTrimChLen%
  intTrimChLen = Len(pTrimCh)

  LTrim = pText

  Do While Left(LTrim, intTrimChLen) = pTrimCh

    LTrim = Mid(LTrim, intTrimChLen + 1)

  Loop

End Function

Public Function RTrim(pText$, Optional pTrimCh$ = " ") As String
'Trims the right end of the string with pTrimCh

  Dim intTrimChLen%
  intTrimChLen = Len(pTrimCh)

  RTrim = pText

  Do While Right(RTrim, intTrimChLen) = pTrimCh

    RTrim = Left(RTrim, Len(RTrim) - intTrimChLen)

  Loop

End Function
```

Comment: Try `Public Function ConcatAll(rngCells As Range, Optional pstrSep as String = "") As String`

Comment: What is the error message you're getting?

Comment: Danger, danger Will Robinson. Why define RTrim and LTrim? Why are you using a Function Name on the right hand side of the assignment operator?

Comment: PtrSafe in VBA? None of your constructs here are designed to run in 64-bit natively (i.e. PtrSafe is not required).

Comment: Thanks BruceWayne and AJD  - I added the string and deleted some of the old code which seemed to work. I am a complete novice at this and as mentioned the macro's were inherited and built a long time ago. I still have a another one that is causing me issues if anyone can hep with this? Its function is to convert 2-D tables to a 1-D table on a new worksheet. Useful for tables with dates as column headers. Start with cell first left of first column selected.

Comment: @hugos: Put another question up (usual [MCVE]) and I should catch it on my scan in the next couple of days. Never know, someone else might also be able to answer it.

Comment: I am unable to paste the code in as I keep getting told it needs spaces or the code needs amended to post? I have tried adding 4 spaces before each line with no joy. Is there a way to upload the file on here? Cheers, Hugos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate issue I see is:

```
Public Function ConcatAll(rngCells As Range, Optional pstrSep$ = "") As String
  'Concatenates the text values in the specified range
  'Useful when coverting weeks to months
  Dim c As Range
  ConcatAll = ""
  For Each c In rngCells
    If c.Value <> "" Then
      ConcatAll = ConcatAll & pstrSep & c.Value ' *** Problem Here
    End If
  Next
  ConcatAll = Mid(ConcatAll, Len(pstrSep) + 1) ' Problem Here
End Function
```

The call to `ConcatAll` on the right hand side would expect to recursively call the Function. The VBA IDE would recognise that as ill-formed code and will stop, which also explains why it is highlighting the line in yellow. Use a temporary variable, and then assign to ConcatAll at the end of the Function.

Review all your remaining code, because you have repeated this error throughout.

Additionally, why redefine in interpreted code Native `RTrim` and `LTrim` functions? VBA is not very good for overloading. At least give them some other name to indicate they are custom functions.

In `LPad` you declare `irpt` but you don't use it.

And you declare a lot of integers. In this day and age, use `Long` at least! Or you can use `Short` if you really think space is an issue.